# Google map markers not removing upon checkbox action

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, symfony, checkbox

I was having some problem trying to filter the list fetched from database upon checkbox action and plot/clear markers onto map. Here is my checkbox declaration in HTML:

```
<div class="">
     <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" name="tags" value="3" onchange="filterList()" unchecked/> MRT Incidents
     </label>
</div>
```

When checkbox onchange, I am filtering the list fetched from database:

```
        function filterList(){
        var tags = document.getElementsByName('tags');
        var i = 0;
        {% for crisis in data %}  
            // code to store fields in database into local var

            for( ; i < tags.length; i++ )
            {
                if( tags[i].checked ) {
                    value = tags[i].value;
                    // I got 4 category 1-fire, 2-flood, 3-mrt, 4-dengue
                        // what I am doing here is check if the checkbox value is equal to the category ID from database, if equal, I push them into the filteredList

                    if(value == category){
                        filteredList.push({
                            // all the fields
                        });
                    }                        break;
                }else{
                        value = tags[i].value;
                        if(value == category){
                            filteredList = [];
                            setMapOnAll(null);
                        }
                    }
            }
        {% endfor %}

    addMarker(filteredList);
    }
```

Then in my addMarker with filteredList parameter:

```
function addMarker(filteredList){ 
        for(var i = 0; i < filteredList.length; i++){
        myLatLng = {lat: parseFloat(filteredList[i].lat), lng: parseFloat(filteredList[i].lng) };

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            clickable: true
        });
}
```

My plotting works weird as well. When I try to check multiple box, let's say I checked the first one, it plotted out. Then I proceed to check the second, it does not plot out but only plot out after I uncheck the first one.

When I try to uncheck the checkbox, the markers on the map are not removed. Instead, it just stay there forever and stacked more and more when I check/uncheck a few times.

Why is it so? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, you are adding the markers over and over again? This probably explains why you are having weird plotting (and you will run out of memory sooner or later). I think you are using the wrong approach though for marker filtering on a Google Map.

You'll need to make changes to your code, here are the main guidelines :

- You need an array/object to store all the marker objects you placed on the map
- You can store the categorie(s) for each marker in that same object i.e.
  `[{markerObj:marker, categories:[1,5,6]}]`
- When a checkbox changes (onchange) you loop through all the checkboxes and get their values then you loop through all the markers in your marker array/object and check if it needs to be filtered or not.
- If you want to hide a marker just call the setVisible function i.e. `markerObj.setVisible(false)`

Here's a working example!
https://jsfiddle.net/fjqagp8o/1/

Comment: Note that in my jsfiddle example I'm using jQuery for event handling

Comment: Hi do you have any idea how to add a cluster map? After I added this line: var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, g_markers,
                    {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'}); it gave me a lot of errors in the console

Comment: Your link doesn't work? I assume you mean this?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Clustering is more complicated, haven't done it in a while and there are various ways of implementing it (including that google documentation example). Last time I had clustering though I would re-init the whole page because it was too complicated otherwise... Wish I could help you more on this sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the markers before adding new ones.

I worked on Android's Google Map API, where I didn't have a method to access existing markers, so I'm not sure whether this is also correct for javascript.
So what I did is put them when adding them in a HashMap and removed them one by one.

That's the code for android:

```
private void clearAllPins() {
    for (Marker marker : markersMap.values()) {  //in your case a simple array might sufice
        marker.remove();
    }
    clientsMarker.clear();
}
```

Comment: But in my case, where do I call this function? Because my marker declaration was separated from the checkbox action method

Comment: You need to call it before `addMarker` or in the begining of it

Comment: do you mind to help me take a look at the checkbox checking part? I tried to print out some message upon uncheck but it does not show

Answer (score 0):

For remove (hide)  a marker you   must use

```
 marker.setMap(null);
```

Your problem seems related  to that fact that you don't have a collection of marker you have added ..then you can't set to null map for this markes 
If you have this collection you can hide all and then add the new ones

Comment: But in my case, where do I call this marker.setMap(null)? Because my marker declaration was separated from the checkbox action method. Is there any way to link both of them together?